# How do you calculate intensity given the energy of a wave?

Tags: energy, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, intensity

I’m a bit confused when it comes to calculating intensity versus energy of a wave.

If I’m given a wave with an energy of 1 eV, how do I calculate its intensity ? I know intensity is usually measured in watts/m^2.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So you need the flux, for example particles per square meter per second.

Comment: How could I get the flux?